# How can I create this table in Latex?

Tags: latex, tabular

How can I create this table in Latex:

[image: How can I create this table in latex]

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows how far you got yourself - I'm sure we can then help with the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the environment `multicolumn` and the package [`multirow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow).

Updated as suggested by SamCarter, to improve the vertical alignment(s):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.09\textwidth}|p{.12\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Thème} & \multirow{2}{*}{ID} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description} & \multirow{2}{*}{Priorité} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Temps\\ approximatif}}\\
\cline{3-4}
 & & En tant que & Je veux & & \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Préparation des\\prototypes de\\rapport}} & 1.1 & \multirow{5}{*}{Administrateur} & Avoir des rapports structurés & \multirow{5}{*}{Élevé} & \multirow{5}{*}{8 Jours}\\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & 1.2 & & Avoir des chartes graphiques dans les rapports & & \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Gestion des\\ rapports}} & 2.1 & \multirow{3}{*}{Administrateur} & Consulter un rapport & \multirow{3}{*}{Élevé} & \multirow{3}{*}{10 Jours}\\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & 2.2 & & Ajouter un rapport & & \\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & 2.3 & & Supprimer un rapport & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the table]

---

Some final adjustments are included here: confront the two codes if you like.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.12\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Thème} & \multirow{2}{*}{ID} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description} & \multirow{2}{*}{Priorité} & \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Temps\\ approximatif}}\\
\cline{3-4}
 & & En tant que & Je veux & & \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Préparation des\\prototypes de\\rapport}} & \multirow{2}{*}{1.1} & \multirow{5}{*}{Administrateur} & Avoir des rapports structurés & \multirow{5}{*}{Élevé} & \multirow{5}{*}{8 Jours}\\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & \multirow{3}{*}{1.2} & & Avoir des chartes graphiques dans les rapports & & \\%%
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Gestion des\\ rapports}} & 2.1 & \multirow{3}{*}{Administrateur} & Consulter un rapport & \multirow{3}{*}{Élevé} & \multirow{3}{*}{10 Jours}\\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & 2.2 & & Ajouter un rapport & & \\
\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
 & 2.3 & & Supprimer un rapport & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption{Caption}
%\label{label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the table updated]

Comment: You get a nicer vertical alignment if you use the actual number of lines instead of rows: `\multirow{5}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Préparation des\\prototypes de\\rapport}} `

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz updated accordingly! Thank you!!